How can I run tasks in background of djagno project?
I need to run a few tasks in background of my Django project and also I didn't know what is __init__.py file in the Main and App directory in my Django project.
I thought myself this file could help me to run my tasks when I run the server with runserver command,
But when I'm trying to put some simple codes in this file, I'm facing with this error django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet..
My idea is to change my Django database in a scheduled way in background.
How can I do that?

There is no "Django event loop". You're not telling us what the "simple codes" are you've put in some file somewhere.

my simple code => print("hello world")

A print("hello world") in an __init__ file will not cause "Apps aren't loaded yet.".

It's because I was import my django models inside init.py

To run tasks in background, research celery. It's a common tool used for this exact case.

You can use "celery" with "beat" to schedule tasks, but if your tasks are light weight you can use "asyncio" to run tasks asynchronously in the background.
